# Replace one regex, then replace second regex in all lines not matching first

Tags: sed

Example task: if a line contains `foo`, replace it with `bar`, otherwise append `baz` to the line.

`sed -e s/foo/bar/ -e s/$/baz/` doesn't work, as the second command gets executed whether or not the first one matches. Is there a way to tell `sed` to go to the next line after a match?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `t` command without a label to start next cycle on successful substitution

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a foo 123
xyz
fore
1foo

$ sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e t -e 's/$/baz/' ip.txt
a bar 123
xyzbaz
forebaz
1bar
```

From manual:

> t label (test)
>
> Branch to label only if there has been a successful
>   substitution since the last input line was read or conditional branch
>   was taken. The label may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is
>   started.

Comment: The best solution. Readable, extensible, and non-redundant!

Answer (score 3):

A more robust way with **`awk`** script:

```
awk '{ if (/foo/) gsub(/foo/, "bar"); else $0 = $0 "baz" }1' file
```

---

Or even shorter:

```
awk '{ if (!gsub(/foo/, "bar")) $0 = $0 "baz"; }1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed -e '/foo/!s/$/baz/g' -e s/foo/bar/g
```

Comment: Thanks! That does solve the stated example task, though I don't see a way to expand it to more strings (i.e. replace a1 with a2, or else replace b1 with b2, or else replace c1 with c2...)

Comment: Also, it means typing the first pattern ("foo") twice, which may not be trivial in practice.

Comment: Please update your question.

Comment: The question looks fine to me, AFAICS you simply answered only a part of it without considering the last part ("Is there a way to tell sed to go to the next line after a match?"). If you'd like to suggest an edit, I'll approve it.

Comment: try my edited answer.

Comment: I see you fixed a syntax error and made the substitution global. It doesn't address my comments above...

Comment: Do note that this won't work correctly if the expansion of `$baz` contains `foo` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
sed -e '/foo/{s//bar/;p;D};s/$/baz/'
```

Explanation:

- Multiple sed commands can be chained with `;` and grouped with `{` ... `}`.
- `/foo/` selects all lines containing the pattern `foo`.
- `s//bar/` is the same as `s/foo/bar/` - an empty pattern means to repeat the last search (in this case, `foo`).
- `p` means to print the pattern space (the line after the substitution).
- `D` means to clear the current line, and go to the next one.
- `s/$/baz/` will perform the second part of the task, i.e. append `baz` to lines which the previous rule left to pass through.

Comment: Technically, `D` strips off the first line off the pattern space and only goes to the next line if the pattern space becomes empty as a result. It would always be the case here as you never add any extra line to the pattern space, but it would still make more sense to simply use `d` instead.

Comment: Note that that code is not portable. Portably, you'd need a `;` between `D` and `}`, and you can't have anything after `}`, you'd need `sed -e '/foo{s//bar;p;d;}' -e 's/$/baz/'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas there's a missing / after the foo. Note we can also use the b branch command here: sed -e '/foo/{s//bar/' -e b -e '}' -e 's/$/baz/'